# Two pens on one canvas in one loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, canvas

This code creates a line that has been torn between the two pens like if you were trying to write on paper while I am grabbing your pen and make you write something I want.

```
var pen=[];
pen[0]=$('#canvas')[0].getContext("2d");
pen[1]=$('#canvas')[0].getContext("2d");
pen[0].beginPath();
pen[1].beginPath();
var y=[[],[]];     // two arrays of pixel values, numbers between 0-100
var x=0;
var i=y[0].length; // the arrays are both the same length
pen[0].moveTo(x,y[0][y[0].length-1]);
pen[1].moveTo(x,y[1][y[1].length-1]);
while(i--){
    x+=2;
    pen[0].lineTo(x,y[0][i]);
    pen[1].lineTo(x,y[1][i]);
    }
pen[0].stroke();
pen[1].stroke();
```

Or best said; if the first array were only the number 100 repeated and the second array was only 0 repeated. I would expect to see two lines being drawn in parallel, but instead I get a zigzag.

Is there a way I can use one canvas and one loop only and get the two separate lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only one context per canvas - I just tested it in Chrome 39:

```
var c = document.createElement('canvas');
var x1 = c.getContext('2d');
var x2 = c.getContext('2d');
x1 === x2;  // true
```

Whilst it *could* be done in one loop if you do a separate `moveTo` and `lineTo` for each line segment *within* the loop (i.e. `moveTo previousPoint, lineTo thisPoint) you'll find that you need to use two loops for best results.

The reason is that Canvas knows how to cleanly join adjacent segments of a line, but only if they're part of a single path.   If you create a new path for each segment the lines won't join up properly.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that $('#canvas')[0].getContext("2d") is only going to return a pointer to the canvas context object, so really it's the same object when you get it for pen 0 and pen 1.

That's probably why you get the zigzag - it's drawing a line from the last drawn pixel on that Context to your new position.

To draw two lines, you'd have to use moveTo(x,y) to move the pen (pointer for the context) without drawing when swapping from one line to the other. Because there's only one context object, I don't think having two pens will work I'm afraid.